# Problem with Android Studio emulator in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, android-studio, dockerfile

I have a Docker container with Android studio 3.6 and it works perfectly. The problem is that the emulator does not run because the Ubuntu machine does not have the CPU to reproduce x86. Does anyone know how to include it in the Dockerfile ?. Thank you.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386

RUN apt-get update

# Download specific Android Studio bundle (all packages).
RUN apt-get install -y curl unzip
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN curl 'https://uit.fun/repo/android-studio-ide-3.6.3-linux.tar.gz' > /studio.tar.gz && \
  tar -zxvf studio.tar.gz && rm /studio.tar.gz


# Install X11
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get install -y xorg


# Install other useful tools
RUN apt-get install -y vim ant

# install Java
RUN apt-get install -y default-jdk

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get install -y libz1 libncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6 libbz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
RUN apt-get install wget
RUN wget 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip' -P /tmp \
&& unzip -d /opt/android /tmp/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip 
RUN apt install xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu
# Clean up
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get purge


ENTRYPOINT [ "android-studio/bin/studio.sh" ]
```

Comment: "the Ubuntu machine does not have the CPU to reproduce x86" is not an error message - as it does not tell what an "Ubuntu machine" even is, which is nothing but noise, but no information about the given scenario. And also, one doesn't need Android Studio at all to run an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using ubuntu in docker, the only way to run an android emulator is to find a system image with "arm" (e.g. `system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a`).

However, even though you're able to run emulator in the container, you will probably be disappointed about that. Since emulator based on arm is typically slow enough to boot, not to mention that running in docker could be even slower.

---

If you really want to create it, you can do something like below.

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a"
avdmanager create avd -n demoTest -d "pixel" -k "system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a" -g "google_apis" -b "armeabi-v7a"
emulator @demoTest -no-window -no-audio -verbose &
```

Once you got this prompt message

> emulator: got message from guest system fingerprint HAL

Your emulator is ready to go.